# what is the exact meaning of compact hausdorff space ? what are example of compact hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology

what  is the  exact meaning  of compact hausdorff space ? what are example  of compact hausdorff ?

My thinking :  compact  = closed  + bounded = finite  subcover

and hausdorff =   disconnected

Im  confused  why   they  (munkre)  combine  compact hausdorff?

Any hints /solution

Comment: your thing is very wrong

Comment: how  @mathworker21.

Comment: $\Bbb R $ is Hausdorff and it is connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not "closed and bounded" - that's not a definition of compactness, that's a theorem characterizing compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. And not "disconnected", either; the Hausdorff separation property has nothing to do with connectedness.

The standard topological definitions:

A set $K$ in a topological space $S$ is compact when, for any collection of open sets that cover $K$ (their union includes $K$), there is some finite subset of them that covers $K$.

A topological space $S$ is Hausdorff when any two points $x$ and $y$ can be separated by neighborhoods - that is, there are open sets $G_x$ and $G_y$ containing $x$ and $y$ respectively such that $G_x\cap G_y$ is empty.

What does this get us? Well, here are two standard results:

- In a Hausdorff space, single-point sets are closed.
- Every compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed.

Talking about compact sets/spaces without that Hausdorff property gets weird. For example, consider the cofinite topology on some infinite set $S$; a set is open iff it's empty or its complement is finite. In that topology, *every* subset of $S$ is compact.

Comment: And the most important reason why compact and Hausdorff are combined: the space is then normal and regular and so we have lots of continuous functions on it (important in analysis).